# How can I write quoted values in en.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I'm writing a script that will add new translations to the en.yml file. However, when I'm dumping them back to the file, my strings are in the following format:

```
some_key: This is the value
```

I'm trying to make the output be:

```
some_key: "This is the value"
```

I'm writing the translations like this:

```
File.open(yaml_file, "w") do |f|
  f.write(translations.to_yaml)
end
```

Where translations is the hash containing all the translations.

Is there any way of adding these quotes, besides manually parsing/rewriting the YAML file?

Comment: Why? YAML doesn't require quoting a string and it's smart enough to do the right thing when it sees embedded spaces. Sounds like worrying too much about something that takes care of itself quite nicely and that won't make much difference.

Comment: Because otherwise, git will show me a ton of differences on the locales file.

Comment: Git will do it once, then will be happy. If something else is generating the files incorrectly, then it should be addressed. I use YAML with Perl, Python and Ruby, and the files are nicely interchangable; I use those languages to generate the YAML file, then modify manually if necessary, but I rely on the YAML engines to do all the heavy lifting, knowing the files generated meet the specs.

Answer (score 5):

The [plan (unquotes) scalar representation](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/flow/plain) is the preferred version when the scalar type doesn't require escaping.

In your case, the String:

```
This is the value
```

doesn't need to be in quotes, thus, if you supply the following YAML:

```
 key: "This is the value"
```

the processor may return:

```
 key: This is the value
```

because they are totally equivalent. However, if you actually want to enter a quoted string as value, then you should use:

```
 key: '"This is the value"'
```

or escape the double quote:

```
 key: "\"This is the value\""
```

I gave a quick look at the [Psych emitter code](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v2.0.2/lib/psych/visitors/emitter.rb#L5-L7), the one invoked by the `to_yaml`, and there doesn't seem to be an option to force quoting on scalar.

I don't even see the option implemented in the [scalar emitter](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v2.0.2/lib/psych/visitors/emitter.rb#L30-L32) code.

```
 def visit_Psych_Nodes_Scalar o
   @handler.scalar o.value, o.anchor, o.tag, o.plain, o.quoted, o.style
 end
```

In other words, you cannot enforce quoting.

Comment: +1 nicely said. Trying to enforce quoting seems like a major time-waster or the result of programming with too little sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for hash conversion

```
def value_stringify(hash)
  hash.each do |k,v|
    if v.kind_of? Hash
      hash[k]= value_stringify(v)
    else
      hash[k]="\"#{v}\""
    end
  end
end
```

Now use the converted hash to store yaml.

```
File.open(yaml_file, "w") do |f|
  f.write(value_stringify(translations).to_yaml)
end
```

Now it should work..

Comment: I have a hash of translations. What do you mean by your code?

Comment: What does this have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: I just tried to enforce quotation to the hash values. I haven’t tried it but I thought it should work if he really wants to enforce the value in quotation.

Answer (score 0):

The format you get is valid YAML. However, if you really want this you could temporarily modify your data before converting it.

Normal:

```
{ foo: "bar" }.to_yaml
# => foo: bar
```

With an space after:

```
{ foo: "bar " }.to_yaml
# => foo: 'bar '
```

Note that you get single quotes and not double quotes. So if you temporarily modifying your data you could add in an placeholder which you remove later.

Example:

```
{ foo: "foo --REMOVE-- ", bar: "bar --REMOVE-- " }.to_yaml
.gsub(' --REMOVE-- ', '')
# => foo: 'foo'
#    bar: 'bar'
```

Comment: I wonder why I should mess my data in this way, when it's perfectly legitimate to have non-quoted scalar values by YAML specification. This is an insane over-complication that could lead to some very hard-to debug bugs.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Actually I can only agree with you. But somehow Tempus wants those quotes and this is an ugly workaround. Guess he already know that his current value already is valid and he should consider listening to your comment.

Comment: The word is spelled "could", not "cud".